# problems with flutter_date_picker_timeline library

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am having problems when using the flutter_date_picker_timeline library with the compatibility of the libraries

This is the error that triggers:

Because flutter_date_picker_timeline >=0.3.0 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and flutter_date_picker_timeline <0.3.0 depends on scroll_to_index ^1.0.6, every version of flutter_date_picker_timeline requires intl ^0.17.0 or scroll_to_index ^1.0.6.
And because gamecenter depends on scroll_to_index ^3.0.1, every version of flutter_date_picker_timeline requires intl ^0.17.0.
So, because gamecenter depends on both intl ^0.18.1 and flutter_date_picker_timeline any, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 65
exit code 65

And these are the dependencies i use in my .yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  scroll_to_index: ^1.0.6
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  intl: ^0.17.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I used these versions and these but I still get the same error:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  scroll_to_index: ^3.0.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  intl: ^0.18.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](/help/non-english-questions). Bilingual posts are not allowed either. Please [edit] the post to be completely in English. If you feel more comfortable writing in Spanish, feel free to try our sister site [es.so].

Comment: can you share the error log after change scroll_to_index: ^3.0.1 and intl: ^0.18.1

Comment: It gives me exactly the same error nothing changes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.